# Explanation of Container From Scratch

Tags: docker, go, containers

I am learning about containers and docker in particular. I just watched this Liz Rice video in which she created a container from scratch (repo is on github.com/lizrice). I wasn't able to follow it completely as I am new to Docker and containers and I don't know Go programming language. However, I wanted to see if someone could give me a very quick explanation of what these items in the code are/trying to accomplish:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "path/filepath"
    "strconv"
    "syscall"
)

// go run main.go run <cmd> <args>
func main() {
    switch os.Args[1] {
    case "run":
        run()
    case "child":
        child()
    default:
        panic("help")
    }
}

func run() {
    fmt.Printf("Running %v \n", os.Args[2:])

    cmd := exec.Command("/proc/self/exe", append([]string{"child"}, os.Args[2:]...)...)
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
        Cloneflags:   syscall.CLONE_NEWUTS | syscall.CLONE_NEWPID | syscall.CLONE_NEWNS,
        Unshareflags: syscall.CLONE_NEWNS,
    }

    must(cmd.Run())
}

func child() {
    fmt.Printf("Running %v \n", os.Args[2:])

    cg()

    cmd := exec.Command(os.Args[2], os.Args[3:]...)
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    must(syscall.Sethostname([]byte("container")))
    must(syscall.Chroot("/home/liz/ubuntufs"))
    must(os.Chdir("/"))
    must(syscall.Mount("proc", "proc", "proc", 0, ""))
    must(syscall.Mount("thing", "mytemp", "tmpfs", 0, ""))

    must(cmd.Run())

    must(syscall.Unmount("proc", 0))
    must(syscall.Unmount("thing", 0))
}

func cg() {
    cgroups := "/sys/fs/cgroup/"
    pids := filepath.Join(cgroups, "pids")
    os.Mkdir(filepath.Join(pids, "liz"), 0755)
    must(ioutil.WriteFile(filepath.Join(pids, "liz/pids.max"), []byte("20"), 0700))
    // Removes the new cgroup in place after the container exits
    must(ioutil.WriteFile(filepath.Join(pids, "liz/notify_on_release"), []byte("1"), 0700))
    must(ioutil.WriteFile(filepath.Join(pids, "liz/cgroup.procs"), []byte(strconv.Itoa(os.Getpid())), 0700))
}

func must(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

In particular, my understanding of a container is that it is a virtualized run-time environment where users can isolate applications from the underlying system and that containers are only isolated groups of processes running on a single host, which fulfill a set of “common” features. I have a good sense of what a container is and trying to accomplish in a broader sense, but I wanted help to understand a specific example like this. If someone understands this well -What is being imported in the import block; what are the cases for in the main function; what is the use of the statement in the run function, and what is being accomplished by the child and cg functions?

I think with my current understanding and going through Docker tutorial, plus an explanation of a real code from scratch example would be extremely beneficial. Just to confirm - this code is not related to Docker itself outside of the code creates a container and Docker is a technology that makes creating containers easier.

Comment: I am thinking in the sense of is this code somehow providing dependencies or libraries or access to these items to the OS somehow (like an API)?

Comment: If you want  to understand the code you _must_ learn Go (start with the Tour of Go), there is no point in asking "What is being imported in the import block[?]". The talk of Liz is very good and explains in much more detail what main does and why, better than can it can be answered on SO. Trying to understand containers by reading code you cannot read because you do not understand the language and how Linux works is pointless.

Comment: I am not trying to learn Go or Linux - I just want to learn from an actual sample of code - what is being implemented to create a container. I understand a container from beginner tutorials and reading articles/tutorials, but if someone can provide a brief explanation of the code and connect it to the tasks a container accomplishes - I think that would solidify my (and others learning containers and Docker, etc) understanding tremendously. I'm not asking about the syntax but wanting to learn about what is being implemented and how it translates from the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She is creating a sort of container by doing this:

- she will execute main.go and pass a command to be executed in the container
- to do this she runs a process that executes the run() function
- in the run() function she prepares a process to be forked that will execute the child() function
- but before actually forking, via syscall.SysProcAttr, she configures a new namespace for:

  - "unix timesharing" (syscall.CLONE_NEWUTS) this essentially will allow to have a separate hostname in the child process
  - PIDs (syscall.CLONE_NEWPID) such that in the "container" she is creating she will have new PIDs starting from 1
  - mounts (syscall.CLONE_NEWNS) will enable the "container" to have separate mounts
- next she executes the fork (cmd.Run())

in the forked process the child() function is executed an here:

- she prepares a control group via cg() that will limit the resources available to the "container", this is done by writing some proper files in the /sys/fs/cgroup/
- next she prepares the command to be executed by using the args passed to main.go
- she uses chroot to a new root under /home/liz/ubuntufs
- she monuts the special fs proc and another temporary fs
- finally she executes the command provided as args to main.go

in the video [containers from scratch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fi7uSYlOdc) she presents all of this very well.
There she executes a bash in the container that sees new PIDs, has a new hostname, and is limited to 20 processes.

To make it work she needed a full ubuntu fs clone under /home/liz/ubuntufs.

The 3 key points to take home are that a continer (well her "container") essentially does this:

- uses namespaces to define what the container will see in terms of
  PIDs/mounts (she did not handle networking in this container example)
- uses chroot to restrict the container to a portion of the filesystem
- uses cgroups to limit resources the container can use

Comment: Thanks! That is really helpful, especially with the summary of 3 key points at the end. Is it safe to say that this is a skeleton of sorts (i.e. a container but without the actual resources attached to it)? Can you give say 1 or 2 resources a container like this might ultimately be used for or might be added to it? Lastly when you say "To make it work she needed a full ubuntu fs clone under /home/liz/ubuntufs." - is this the "image"?

Comment: well there are resources attached to it: in the filesystem she uses a folder, dedicated to the container, so a fraction of the fs in the os is "in use" to the container. root in the os can touch it, other containers running in parallel will not have access to it. Each process running in it will use threads, semaphores, pids  etc so this are OS resources. The actual resourses are attached to it "on demand" depending what you run in it. Other resources are netowrking resoursces like a port to be opened say by a server you run. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces#Namespace_kinds

Comment: e.g. Docker does the port remapping: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Comment: about the image: yes the files she uses are kind of an image to start with. You can execute an image as is in docker or you can build your own applicatiion with a dockerfile and when you use the command "FROM" in the dockerfile you are naming from what image you are starting, i.e. usually an os that carries the files you need as base

Comment: indeed the video is very instructive, and reading around I found you can get something similar with a single command "sudo unshare --fork --pid --mount-proc --uts bash" in this case executing "unshare ... bash" one executes a bash unsharing the indicated namespaces: this means detaching from the default nameescapes so taht in that bash you can rename the host, mount something that is not seen by other preocesses and you'll have separated pids as well

Answer (score -1):

Due to my lack of experience in GO & limited experience with custom docker containers, I can not confirm what this code does.

*While this is not directly answering the question in the title, I want to provide an answer that helps you learn the basics in docker to get you started.*

You're understanding of containers is correct. Try to find a tutorial that uses a simpler example in a language you're familiar with .

One simple example to get you started would be to create a container of your preferred linux OS, attach the docker container to your current terminal then run few OS specific commands within the container (such as installing a software inside the container or any linux command) .

Comment: Thanks - I am following a couple tutorials including the one from Docker itself which is good and useful. If this code in the sample is not formally 'creating a container' (it is part of a larger repo, but this is the main part) - what is this code accomplishing then?

Comment: "the code doesn't seem to have anything to do with running or creating a container, it's more of a sample code to run inside the container." - no. That code is *actually* creating a container. It's doing essentially the same as Docker does when you run a container, although greatly simplified. The code sets up a "container", and then runs the same binary, with a different parameter just to trigger the actual code rather than the container setup code.

Comment: @jeremy - that code *is* formally creating a container. The answer above is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Bruno - can you possibly respond in terms of just briefly explaining (can be at a high level or broad sense) what the parts are trying to accomplish -  What is being imported in the import block; what are the cases for in the main function; what is the use of the statement in the run function, and what is being accomplished by the child and cg functions?

Comment: Not too sure, but it seems to be creating & mounting some folders. This could be part of a more advanced customised container setup, but it's not something that would be part of a beginner tutorial. 
Due to my lack of experience in GO & limited experience with custom docker containers, I don't have a complete answer, more of a nudge in the right direction to learning docker .

Comment: hi @BrunoReis . I've removed my assumptions for the answer while keeping it relevant . While I don't see how this code is used to create a container, I should learn more about creating custom container before I assume either way .

Comment: @jeremy in short, this program is supposed to run with a "run" argument initially (as seen in the comment above the main function). The main function checks whether the first argument is "run" or "child". If it is "run", it does some initial setup and then uses exec.Command to launch another process from the same binary, but now using the "child" argument. This new process will again start at main, but now with the "child" case matching. It then uses a ton of syscalls to setup a container: an isolated environment where the process will run. This isolated environment (...)

Comment: (...) is what many people (wrongly) call a "lightweight virtual machine". It's basically using a bunch of features of the Kernel that isolates that process from the rest of the processes running in the OS, prepares a new process tree, gives it an isolated view of the file system etc, and FINALLY invokes the binary that was passed as an argument after "run". This binary will then run in isolation.

Comment: @MichaelHabib note that the code above isn't relate to *Docker containers*. It's about the more general concept of *containers*, which is much more than just Docker. Think of Docker as a (very powerful and sophisticated) tool to run containers. The code above is functionally equivalent to Docker itself: it setups up isolation, and then runs an application with that isolation. Call that code "micro-Docker", if you will.

Comment: I see, thanks @BrunoReis , that makes sense. I came across these folder names & the `Chroot` command a while back, after trying to fix grub boot issues. I guess the idea was to mount & isolate the target OS files then execute the grub commands in the new context.

Comment: Bruno thanks - I think that was very helpful - if you want to put that as an answer to the question, I'll mark it correct

Comment: Ok got it, I understand that this isn't necessarily related to Docker (Docker is its own platform for containerization), but I wanted to understand how someone could start with code and make a container as opposed to using an interface or some other tool